# How to divide a DataFrame into groups using index label and perform operation to find 3 largest in a particular column according to each index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe like this:

```
STNAME         CTYNAME           POPESTIMATE    
Alabama        Autauga County     54660
Alabama        Baldwin County     183193
Alabama        Barbour County     27341
Alabama        Bibb County        22861
Alabama        Blount County      57373  
.......        ...............    .....
Wyoming        Sweetwater County  43593
Wyoming        Teton County       21297
Wyoming        Uinta County       21102

.......      .............      ......  
.......        .............       .....  

and so on............
```

Here i have to find out three most populous cities(CTYNAME) for each state and sum up them(using POPESTIMATE) for each state and we can call that as Population of each state,and from that data of population(only three most populous cities for each state) I have to find out three most populous states and print them in a list.
I have tried out this using multiple method in pandas library but nothing has worked for me.
Can some one please help me with this.

Comment: Take a look at `pd.DataFrame.groupby` and `nlargest`

Answer (score 0):

Spliting df:

```
df = df.groupby('STNAME',as_index=True)
print(df.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.nlargest(3).index)))
```